# Razor View Race Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, razor, race-condition

In a custom razor engine, derived from RazorViewEngine, I've spotted what I think is unstable code:

```
    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = AddViewDynamicFormat(controllerContext, viewName).ToArray();
        AreaViewLocationFormats = AddAreaViewDynamicFormat(controllerContext, viewName).ToArray();
        return base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
    }
```

My concern is that when two requests are being processed "at the same time," the first will set the location formats as it needs, but before it can use them - the second threaded request might have a chance to set the location formats a different way.  The rest gets ugly.

Is this a valid concern?  Said differently, does ASP.NET MVC guarantee that the Razor View engine will handle exactly one request at a time?  I doubt that is the case.

Likewise, if there was one razor view engine *object* per request, then this would be ok.  But I also don't believe that is the case.

**UPDATE**
I have confirmed that this is a race condition.  I have also found an article showing a [dynamic expansive razor search example](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx), which solves the problem without a race condition (though I still wonder if it has a caching issue).

Comment: So... what are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe you need another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm nearly positive that the RazorViewEngine isn't meant to be modified at run-time, but merely configured in Global.asax Application_Start. I believe the RazorViewEngine instance exists for the life of the App Domain after startup.

If you need to add additional ViewLocationFormats or AreaViewLocationFormats do it in Application_Start. Application_Start is guaranteed to run only once per App Domain.

Answer (score 0):

Are `ViewLocationFormats` and `AreaViewLocationFormats` virtual? If so, you can put that value in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection and retrieve it from the overridden properties.

Comment: No, they are not virtual properties, despite the irony of being defined in an MVC class called "VirtualPathProviderEngine".